# Invalid token 'else' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, record, bold

i try to highlight record ...like when any one wants to upload documet then in repeater i try to highlight this new record and when user click on this document then this becomes as normal position means not  highlight

```
<tr style='<%#if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedType")== 1) 
 { %> background-color: yellow;  <% }
   else { <% background-color: white;
    <%} %>'>
```

but it shows me error

```
CS1519: Invalid token 'else' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Source Error:

Line 128:  style='<%#if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedType")== 1) 
Line 129:  { %> background-color: yellow;  <% }
Line 130:  else { <% background-color: white;
Line 131:  <%} %>'>
Line 132:  <%--<td>
```

how to solve?

Comment: It should be: else { %>

Comment: You should really be doing this logic in the code behind, before binding the values, rather than in the template.  If the bound column is simply the color you can just bind the background color to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use control structures (like if statements) inside of a databinding expression tag (which is `<%# %>`), but you also can't use `DataBinder` inside of a regular tag (`<% %>`).

I'd recommend just using the conditional operater inline like this:

```
<tr style='background-color: <%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedType") ? "yellow" : "white" %>'>
```

Comment: it shoW me error "if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedType")== 1) " in this line ERROR IS CS0103: The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yea, that's correct, you can only use DataBinder inside of `<%# %>` tags. I've got anohter idea, will edit

Comment: @user3265377 Try now, that should work for you I think.

Comment: it shows me error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: @user3265377 Try now. You needed a cast.

Comment: this shows me error ...Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: You gotta figure this out on your own. Figure out what `ViewedTypes` is, apparently it's not an `int` even though that's what you're comparing it to. If it's a string, then use `(string) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedTypes") == "1"` instead.

Comment: and if it is bit... then what would i do

Comment: Cast it to a bool, use `(bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedTypes")`

Comment: hey i try this ..                               <tr style='background-color: <%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedID")== "1" ? "yellow" : "white" %>'>
and it shows me error ....
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: `<tr style='background-color: <%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedID") ? "yellow" : "white" %>'>`

Comment: what does what about 1 mean?

Comment: Yes. a `bit` in sql is a `bool` in c#. That means that you can just use it directly and not have to compare it to 1.

Comment: No. Literally just put this and try it. `<tr style='background-color: <%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedID") ? "yellow" : "white" %>'>`

Comment: Most of this thread isn't questions about data binding - it's moved onto questions about types in C#.HTML/JavaScript aren't strongly typed, but once you go into a code block, you're in strongly-typed land. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<tr style='background-color: <%# ChooseColor((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ViewedType")) #>;'>
```

where

```
protected string ChooseColor(int viewedType){
    if (viewedType == 1) return "yellow"; else return "white";
}
```

Comment: Nice option too, I think you'll need to add a cast in the markup since DataBinder.Eval returns an object. Something like `<%# ChooseColor((int) DataBinder....`

Comment: @JohnSaunders the code which is protected string is in .aspx or in .aspx.cs

Comment: .aspx.cs. There should be only a bare minimum of C# code in the .aspx file. Nothing more than simple data binding expressions.